# Converting to binary string in Python Issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, jpeg, filesize

I am trying to read a jpg in python3, then convert to a binary-string and then write back to a jpg with that binary string. (Actually the motive is to play-with/compress the binary string, if possible)... but when I write it back the size of jpg changes (reduces). I don’t know why it should change. Any ideas ?

Here is the code:

```
import io
import sys
from PIL import Image
image = open("53.jpg", "rb")
imageBinaryBytes = image.read()

c = bin(int.from_bytes(imageBinaryBytes, byteorder=sys.byteorder))
d = int(c, 2).to_bytes((len(c)-2),byteorder=sys.byteorder )

imageStream = io.BytesIO(d)
imageFile = Image.open(imageStream)
imageFile.save("53-out.jpg")
```

Now 53.jpg was size 53KB (52816)
and 53-out.jpg turns out to be 40 KB (40061)

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you define as "binary string"? `imageBinaryBytes` *is* a "binary string" already.

Comment: And the reason it reduces in size is likely because `PIL` recompresses the image using a higher compression ratio.

Comment: A string comprising of 0s and 1s as stored in the system (order)

Comment: And why do you want that? It doesn't seem to have any use in this example.

Comment: So, is there a way to store it exactly it was in PIL ?

Comment: I am writing a compression algorithm which will attempt to reduce the size of the binary string without loss... Not here in the code, but c will be reduced

Comment: "Exactly as it was in PIL" means very little. However PIL stores the image in memory is an implementation detail that's irrelevant. Likely an array of RGB values for each pixel of the image. You can only decide how you want to output it. In this case, you're using JPG with default settings, so it's going to be compressed. Use BMP or TIFF to output as a "raw" format, but that still doesn't necessarily have much to do with "how it was in PIL".

Comment: To illustrate what you're doing: read JPEG file contents as `binary` → transform that into a `str` with "0101010" → transform it back into `binary` → have PIL parse the JPEG into some internal representation (you could have skipped the previous two steps for that) → have PIL write the image to a new JPEG, recompressing it. — If you want to do your own compression, PIL is unnecessary, you'd just write your own `binary` data straight to a file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @deceze
So then reading-file in binary and writing binary back is independent of the format... The compression format will be different ofcourse which I will store in proprietary format... but I want to uncompress my format into “010101” string (loss less) and then recreate the file back as it is.

Comment: Well then don’t use PIL. Just `with open('img.jpg', 'w') as f: f.write(my_bin)`.